# How to remove every file of nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I had a problem with the installation of express. Problem was I had two version installed in two different directory. I tried to uninstall the two versions deleting files of node and the directory node_module. Then I installed one more time node, but now npm doesn't work:

/usr/bin/npm: /usr/bin/nodejs: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

What I have to do? I only thinked that best way is remove every files of nodejs and reinstall it, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed node without removing the older version you had installed. You can follow the instructions given here to remove all nodejs fies :https://npmjs.org/doc/removing-npm.html

After doing the above also do `hash -r` to remove npm location from hashmap, before reinstalling it.